# How to count subquery records in where clause using ActiveRecord?

Tags: sql, activerecord

Given two ActiveRecord models:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

with `Bar` having an attribute `color` with possible values `red` and `green`, I'd like to 
get the `foos`, which have more red `bars`, than green `bars`.

So far, I was able to achive this like so:

```
red_bars_sql = Bar.select('COUNT(*)').where(color: 'red').where('foo.id = bar.foo_id').to_sql
green_bars_sql = Bar.select('COUNT(*)').where(color: 'green').where('foo.id = bar.foo_id').to_sql

Foo.where("(#{red_bars_sql}) > (green_bars_sql)")
```

This performs reasonably well.

I'd like to know if there is an alternative approach to this problem. Also, is there a way
to implement this current approach with less SQL and more ActiveRecord (avoid the hack of
interpolating sql in the `where` clause of `Foo`).

I tried something along the lines:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bars
  has_many :reds, -> { reds }, class_name: 'Bar'
  has_many :greens, -> { greens }, class_name: 'Bar'
end

class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo

  scope :reds, -> { where(color: 'red') }
  scope :greens, -> { where(color: 'green') }
end
```

and then tried grouping (`Foo.joins(:reds, :greens).group(...).having(...)`), but I didn't built it correctly and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SQL this can be done as one query with something like this (example with PostgreSQL, other DBs have something similar for conditional aggregations):

```
SELECT
  foo.*
FROM foos
INNER JOIN bars ON foos.id = bars.foo_id
GROUP BY foos.id
HAVING 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN bars.color = 'red' THEN 1 END) 
    > COUNT(CASE WHEN bars.color = 'green' THEN 1 END)
```

If you prefer AR it will still contain a lot of SQL, but is supposed to be something like:

```
Foo.joins(:bars).group(:id)
  .having(
    "COUNT(CASE WHEN bars.color = 'red' THEN 1 END) " \
      "> COUNT(CASE WHEN bars.color = 'green' THEN 1 END)"
  )
```